# Help me convert this 2d array code from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php

Please help me re-write this code sample in PHP to C#:

```
$stringArray = array();
$stringArray['field1'] = 'value1';
$stringArray['field2'] = 'value2';
$stringArray['field3'] = 'value3';

foreach ($stringArray as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ': ' . $value;
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Named arrays do not exist in C#. An alternative is to use a [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to recreate a similar structure.

```
Dictionary<string, string> stringArray = new Dictionary<string, string>();
stringArray.Add("field1", "value1");
stringArray.Add("field2", "value2");
stringArray.Add("field3", "value3");
```

In order to iterate through them, you can use the following:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in stringArray ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: This also has the advantage of being strongly typed.  Gotta love Generics.

Comment: @Steve: Best language feature implemented in CLR 2.0 **by far**.

Comment: Indeed.  Most of the time these low level optimizations aren't really appreciated because it's often not where the bottleneck lies.  But one of the few times I was able to observe the performance advantage was with some AI I wrote for a Tic Tac Toe game.  Once I made the switch to Generics and eliminated the need for any type conversion whatsoever, I improved performance by over 25%.

Comment: There is also the StringDictionary class if you are only using strings in your values. I'm really not sure if it is better than a generic dictionary<string,string>, but it is a strongly typed hashtable, meant to work specifically with strings..

Comment: just to complement my other post, you would use it like this:       StringDictionary myCol = new StringDictionary();
      myCol.Add( "red", "rojo" );
      myCol.Add( "green", "verde" );
      myCol.Add( "blue", "azul" );

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = new Dictionary<String, String>
              {
                  { "field1", "value1" },
                  { "field2", "value2" },
                  { "field3", "value3" }
              }
```

Or without the collection initializer.

```
var map = new Dictionary<String, String>();

map["field1"] = "value1";
map["field2"] = "value2";
map["field3"] = "value3";
```

There is even a specialized class `StringDictionary` to map string to strings in the often overlooked namespace `System.Collections.Specialized`, but I prefer `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` because it implements a richer set of interfaces.

Comment: Sorry my fault for not being more specific, wanted to add one at a time.  Also added a loop thing at the end, upvoted anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to recreate an associative array - in C# I would usually use a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,string> stringArray = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

and then you can assign values in two ways

```
stringArray["field1"] = "value1";
stringArray.Add("field2","value2");
```

Dictionaries can be used to store any key/value pair combination, such as:

```
Dictionary<int,string>()
Dictionary<long,KeyValuePair<string,long>>()
etc.
```

If you absolutely know that you only need a key that is a string that will be returning a value that is a string then you can also use a NameValueCollection

```
NameValueCollection stringArray = new NameValueCollection();
```

and again you can use the same two methods to add values

```
stringArray["field1"] = "value1";
stringArray.Add("field2","value2");
```

Both datatypes also have other convenience methods like

```
stringArray.Clear(); // make it empty
stringArray.Remove("field1"); // remove field1 but leave everything else
```

check out your intellisense in visual studio for more good stuff

*Additional nodes*

Note that a `NameValueColelction` does not (solely) provide a one-to-one mapping - you can associate multiple values with a single name.

```
var map = new NameValueCollection();

map.Add("Bar", "Foo");
map.Add("Bar", "Buz");

// Prints 'Foo,Buz' - the comma-separated list of all values
// associated with the name 'Bar'.
Console.WriteLine(map["Bar"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Daniel - I don't use NameValueCollections that often (knowingly...) - cheers